# How to retrieve ID from other table for composite key in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables, tblstaff, tblgrade, tblperformance and tblcategory. In tblperformance, there are 3 keys. perID is a primary key. staffNo and catID are composite keys.

I use catID as auto increment in tblcategory and staffNo, I fill in by myself for tblstaff. My sql statement has no problem when I run the code.

How can I retrieve staffNo and catID from tblstaff and tblcategory to insert in tblperformance using insert statement in sql?

```html
<?php
$staffNo=$_POST['staffNo'];
$staffName=$_POST['staffName'];

$grade=$_POST['grade'];
$gradePosition=$_POST['gradePosition'];
$gradeDepartment=$_POST['gradeDepartment'];

$catTechnical=$_POST['catTechnical'];
$catOtherTechnical=$_POST['catOtherTechnical'];
$catTechnicalDescription=$_POST['catTechnicalDescription'];
$catOtherTechnicalDescription=$_POST['catOtherTechnicalDescription'];
$catWeightage=$_POST['catWeightage'];

$perReqScore=$_POST['perReqScore'];
$perActScore=$_POST['perActScore'];
$perAction=$_POST['perAction'];
$perOtherAction=$_POST['perOtherAction'];
$perTrainingIlsas=$_POST['perTrainingIlsas'];
$perTrainingPublic=$_POST['perTrainingPublic'];

$sql1="INSERT INTO tblstaff(staffNo, staffName)VALUES('$staffNo', '$staffName')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

$sql2="INSERT INTO tblgrade(grade, gradePosition, gradeDepartment)VALUES('$grade', '$gradePosition', '$gradeDepartment')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

$sql3="INSERT INTO tblcategory(catTechnical, catOtherTechnical, catTechnicalDescription, catOtherTechnicalDescription,catWeightage)
VALUES('$catTechnical', '$catOtherTechnical', '$catTechnicalDescription', '$catOtherTechnicalDescription', '$catWeightage')";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

$sql4="INSERT INTO tblperformance(perReqScore, perActScore, perAction, perOtherAction, perTrainingIlsas, perTrainingPublic)
VALUES('$perReqScore','$perActScore', '$perAction', '$perOtherAction', '$perTrainingIlsas', '$perTrainingPublic')";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);

if(($result1 || $result2) || ($result3 || $result4) == TRUE)
{
echo "<script>alert('Data inserted successfully')</script>";
}

else 
{
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve data, in your case:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblcategory ORDER BY catID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $latestCatID = $row["0"];
}
```

Where `SELECT * FROM tblcategory ORDER BY catID DESC LIMIT 1` gives you the last record you inserted.

With staffNo, you can just use `$staffNo`

Finally, your insert into tblperformance will look like this:

```
$sql4="INSERT INTO tblperformance(catID, staffNo, perReqScore, perActScore, perAction, perOtherAction, perTrainingIlsas, perTrainingPublic)
VALUES('$latestCatID', '$staffNo', '$perReqScore','$perActScore', '$perAction', '$perOtherAction', '$perTrainingIlsas', '$perTrainingPublic')";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);
```

Be careful with `'$latestCatID'` and `'$staffNo'`, you don't need the single quotes `''` if you are using an integer data type.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm sorry i didn't mention that i use mysql instead of mysqli. i have try your answer and change it into mysql statement. But I get an error on $result ->fetch_assoc(); Did you know how to change it into mysql statement? I'm sorry I'm feeling stupid to ask about this question but I'll try to learn. did you know the right syntax for this statement?

$category = result_fetch_assoc();

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer with code using mysql_query, see if that works.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works great. That's really what I want :)